# Testing whether a NumPy array contains a particular row

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create an n-by-2 NumPy array, and then test whether it contains a particular 1-by-2 array (i.e. whether it contains a particular row).

Here is my code:

```
x = np.array([0, 1])
y = np.array([2, 3])
z = np.vstack((x, y))
if x in z:
    print "Yes"
```

But this gives me the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Please could somebody explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may be using an older version of numpy since on `1.10` this does work;

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 1])
>>> y = np.array([2, 3])
>>> z = np.vstack((x, y))
>>> x in z
True
>>> np.__version__
'1.10.1'
```

That said, it does **not** do what you want:

```
>>> z
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
>>> x
array([0, 1])
>>> x in z
True
```

as [commented out here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/de591ba203d8f795dac2edb31b6f8fb236680b9c/numpy/core/src/multiarray/sequence.c#L117), `x in z` is equivalent of `(x == z).any()`, not kind of row search that you want.

---

To implement what you need, you may do:

```
>>> (z == x).all(axis=1).any()
True
```